# So I'm getting a "No matching function for call to..." error

Tags: c++, function, pointers, reference

So I'm getting a "No matching function for call to..." error and my instructor hasn't been helpful in the slightest. I am currently learning C++ and am at a "pointers" unit. My instructor has had us rebuild a single program by adding various components and changing the underlying structure but it's created significant problems for me.

I have three functions that are listed as an error in the debugger as "No matching function to call to...". I've looked over the function prototypes, definitions and arguments and everything appears to line up.

Any thoughts?

Note: Errors listed in bold.

```
int main()
{
//Arrays to store item names, prices, counts,etc.
    string itemName[4] = {"Virtual Personal Networks", "Firewalls", "Security Cameras", "Encryption Tools"};

    int itemQuantity[4] = {0};
    int itemPrice[4] = {10, 20, 30, 40};
    int itemTotalPrice[5] = {0};
    int itemsTotal = 0;

    //Pointer variables.
    string * pItemName = &itemName[0];
    int * pItemQuantity = &itemQuantity[0];
    int * pItemPrice = &itemPrice[0];
    int * pItemTotalPrice = &itemTotalPrice[0];
    int * pItemsTotal = &itemsTotal;

    welcomeUser(); //Displays Welcome Message
    getProducts(pItemName[0], pItemPrice[0]); //Displays Products for Selection
    itemsTotalPrice(*pItemTotalPrice, *pItemPrice, *pItemQuantity, *pItemsTotal); //Calculate Total price order.
    itemSelection(*pItemName, *pItemPrice, *pItemQuantity, *pItemTotalPrice, *pItemsTotal)
    return 0;
}
```

```
//Functions defined outside of the main function.
void itemSelection(string *pItemName[], int *pItemPrice[], int *pItemQuantity[], int *pItemTotalPrice[], int *pItemsTotal[])

void getProducts(string *pItemName[], int *pItemPrice[])

itemsTotalPrice(*pItemTotalPrice, *pItemPrice, *pItemQuantity, *pItemsTotal);
```

Any help would be incredibly appreciated. I can provide any other code in case I missed something. The full program is 300 lines long so this is a good chunk of the information related to the problem.

Edit: Removed nonfunctional bold post modifiers. Will take a closer look shortly on other comments.

Comment: I used the listed **info** to bold items but it appears to not have emboldened the issues. The errors primarily appear in the function names.

Comment: Please include the complete error message in the question. Even if it is hard to decipher for you, it often does contain useful information

Comment: please remove the `**` from the code. Making code bold doesn't work and it makes your code hard to read

Comment: Regarding the functions defined outside of the main function.  **Where** are they defined?  How are you compiling & linking the code?

Comment: and concerning the 300 lines, please read about [mcve]. If you cannot condense the problem to a small example of ~20 lines of code then you have a problem more severe than passing the wrong parameters to functions. Creating a mcve does require work, but it pays off. All we need to see is the functions and how you call them

Comment: Are you aware that a compiler reads your source from top to bottom literally? If a function is called somewhere it must be at least declared atop of the call. Definition of function might be anywhere. (That's the job of the linker to sort this out.) But the compiler doesn't accept a call of a function for which it doesn't know how it has to be called.

Comment: Just in case, that the order of function definitions is in fact your problem. An [**mcve on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/78a68743683a8b04) to illustrate your issue.